# How to implement mid-model loss function with both true and pred values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

What I'm trying to do is implement the loss functions from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00104).

The loss function utilizes multiple separate models that are linked in series and parallel. The first model is a low-fidelity model, the second model is a set of two, parallel models, and the last model is a physics informed neural network (PINN). My specific implementation will not be using the PINN.

The prescribed loss function needs the MSE of the low-fidelity output and the gradient of the low-fidelity output (that's how I understand the formula at least) as well as the MSE of the high-fidelity output, the MSE of the PINN output, and lastly a regularization term.

So,

1. How do I get the MSE of a mid-model output?
2. How do I calculate the gradient terms for y* and y?
3. Given that there are probably few different ways to implement this,
   which method would be the best in terms of clarity? (I realize this is a bit subjective)

My own searches have me concluding that I will need to utilize the `Model.add_loss()` function by either adding it to a subclassed layer or by adding it via the tf.keras.Model API. This all makes sense. The part where I am having issues is getting `y_true` to the location where I implement the loss function. The best thing I have found so far is the use of dictionaries in model declaration inputs and outputs:

```
model = tf.keras.Model( inputs = some_dict{'input_name':input_name}, 
            outputs = another_dict{'output_name0': output_name0, 
            'output_name1': output_name1, name = 'my_name' }
```

I found the general idea [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/shared-models-and-custom-losses-in-tensorflow-2-keras-6776ecb3b3a9). I did not even know that the use of dicts was even possible for `tf.keras.Model` inputs prior to reading this. My hang-up is that the author ends up using some of the "outputs" as inputs for evaluation. My current framework looks a bit like this

```
    def load_model0():
        init_model = [ *Load model of choice* ]
        input0 = tf.keras.Input((size,),name = 'input_zero')
        x = input0
        model0_out = init_model(x)

        model = tf.keras.Model( inputs=input0, outputs = {'model0_out': model0_out}, 
                name = "model0")
        return model

    def load_model1():
        init_model = [ *Load model of choice* ]
        input1 = tf.keras.Input((size,),name = 'input_one')
        x = input0
        model1_out = init_model(x)

        model = tf.keras.Model( inputs=input1, outputs = {'model1_out': model1_out}, 
                name = "model1")
        return model

    def link_models(model0,model1):
        input0 = tf.keras.Input((size0,), name = "first_input")
        input1 = tf.keras.Input((size1,), name = "second_input")

        first_model_out = model0(input0)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate([first_model_out,input1])
        linked_out = model1(x)

        linked_model = tf.keras.Model( intputs = {'input0': input0, 'input1': input1},
                        outputs = {"linked_out": linked_out, [ *insert confusion* ]}

        loss_function0 = tf.keras.losses.MSE([*insert model0 true values here*],first_model_out)
        linked_model.add_loss(loss_function0)
        loss_function1 = tf.keras.losses.MSE([*insert model1 true values here*], linked_out )
        linked_model.add_loss(loss_function1)
```

As of right now, I do not know whether the `model.add_loss()` loss functions can be used in conjunction with a regular loss function/class in `Model.compile()`. How do I get the true values? How do I run `Model.fit()` to make this work?

EDIT: In response to Laplace Ricky.
I have a set of three networks connected end to end. The first network doesn't matter here. The second network outputs dimension 15. The third network outputs dimension 40. The setup of the final model looks something like this:

```
# top/first model takes input dimension of (40,)
inputs = tf.keras.Input((40,))

# middle_out dimension is (size,15)
middle_out = middle_model(top_model(inputs))

linked_model = tf.keras.Model( inputs = inputs,
                   outputs = [bottom_model(middle_out),middle_out],
                   name = 'linked_model' )
```

I set the loss and optimizer like this:

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
loss = [ tf.keras.losses.MSE, tf.keras.losses.MSE ] 
linked_model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = losses)
```

and fit with

```
y_list = [data0,data1]
linked_model.fit(x,y_list, epoch = 10, batch_size = 32 )
```

where data0 is dimension (size,40), and
data1 is dimension (size,15).

This produces the error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 15 and 40 for '{{node Mul_6}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](IteratorGetNext:3, Cast_4)' with input shapes: [160,15], [40].
```

I have also tried the dict alternative method (with the necessary changes to the expected output in `model.fit()`):

```
 loss = {'middle_model': tf.keras.losses.MSE,
         'bottom_model': tf.keras.losses.MSE}
        # Tensorflow gave me a very explicit error saying I need 
        # the name of the bottom model as opposed to the name of the
        # linked model
```

Comment: Please find my colab here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ao3u1GrylD-TTdZsQVOJ58tsFzK6FhjT

Comment: It is difficult to tell where the shape error comes from in your provided information. The error does not lie in what you have provided. The colab has a top model, a mid model(output shape 15) and a bottom model(output shape 40) and the initial input shape 40 as what you specified and now it is working. Hopefully it can help you debug.

Comment: @LaplaceRicky The problem has been solved. I had an issue with a dimension constrained Metric, and I didn't differentiate between the two outputs with separate metrics. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_loss()` is for losses that don't require the information of the data(y_true) like, for example, regularization losses.

One way to achieve what you want is to create model with multiple outputs.

Example Codes:

```
tf.random.set_seed(88883)
np.random.seed(88883)
#defining toy example model0 and model1
inputs=tf.keras.Input((10,))
model0=tf.keras.Model(inputs,Dense(5)(inputs),name='outputs_0')
inputs=tf.keras.Input((15,))
model1=tf.keras.Model(inputs,Dense(7)(inputs),name='outputs_1')

#define the big model
inputs_0=tf.keras.Input((10,),name='inputs_0')
inputs_1=tf.keras.Input((10,),name='inputs_1')
first_model_output=model0(inputs_0)
x=tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([first_model_output,inputs_1])
second_model_output=model1(x)

bigmodel=tf.keras.Model([inputs_0,inputs_1],[first_model_output,second_model_output])

bigmodel.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD())

#generating data
x0=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.rand(64,10))
x1=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.rand(64,10))
y0=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.rand(64,5))
y1=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.rand(64,7))
ds=tf.data.Dataset.zip(({'inputs_0':x0,'inputs_1':x1},{'outputs_0':y0,'outputs_1':y1}))
ds=ds.batch(4)

bigmodel.fit(ds,epochs=5)
'''
Epoch 1/5
16/16 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.7648 - outputs_0_loss: 0.4287 - outputs_1_loss: 0.3361
Epoch 2/5
16/16 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5918 - outputs_0_loss: 0.3294 - outputs_1_loss: 0.2625
Epoch 3/5
16/16 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.5036 - outputs_0_loss: 0.2728 - outputs_1_loss: 0.2308
Epoch 4/5
16/16 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.4530 - outputs_0_loss: 0.2388 - outputs_1_loss: 0.2142
Epoch 5/5
16/16 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.4214 - outputs_0_loss: 0.2172 - outputs_1_loss: 0.2042
'''
```

`bigmodel.fit()` will be optimizing the **sum** of MSE of `first_model_output` with `y0` and MSE of `second_model_output` with `y1`.

Comment: Do you know how I might be able to add the MSE of the gradient of the outputs of the first model (i.e. low-fidelity model in the paper) with doing the same for the second model. This is part of the reason as to why the `add_loss()` function may be necessary here. It may not have been intended for this purpose, but it can be used as referenced in this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/shared-models-and-custom-losses-in-tensorflow-2-keras-6776ecb3b3a9).

Comment: In the example showed in your question, it is not necessary to use `add_loss()`. If you use `add_loss()`, you will have to pass labels as **input** to the model which will work the same but is confusing and reducing clarity. In cases where `add_loss()` must be used to use `model.fit()`, I would even prefer using custom training loop in which the loss function and training process gets the max clarity. `add_loss()` is just a shortcut way and it is only recommended when the loss function and training process is simple.

Comment: @"Laplace Ricky" - This will not work unless both sets of outputs are the same dimension. I'm currently trying to figure that part out. Could you update your answer to provide an example of how that is supposed to be done.

Comment: Can you describe more clearly about the problem your are encountering and what example do you want?

Comment: I have updated my original post to reflect my error.